# VBA Getting all Google Search result

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I have a list of search keywords in column C and would like to get all the title and URLs from the first 3 page Google search result and paste them in column G and H. However, i have some problems in getting the URLs and i dont know why the next page button does not work.

Here is my code:

```
Sub SearchGoogle()

    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    Dim keywords As Range
    Set keywords = Worksheets("Google").Range("C2:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    Dim row As Long
    row = 2
    
    Dim page As Integer
    
        For Each keyword In keywords
            IE.Visible = True
            IE.navigate "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & keyword & "&start=" & ((page - 1) * 10)
        For page = 1 To 3
            Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
                Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
            Loop
            Dim titles As Object
            Set titles = IE.document.getelementsbytagname("h3")
            Dim title As Variant
            For Each title In titles
                Worksheets("Google").Cells(row, "G").Value = title.innerText
                Worksheets("Google").Cells(row, "H").Value = title.ParentNode.href
                row = row + 1
            Next title
        
            If page < 3 Then
                Dim nextButton As Object
                Set nextButton = IE.document.getelementbyid("pnnext")
                If Not nextButton Is Nothing Then
                    nextButton.Click
                    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
                        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
                    Loop
                End If
            End If
    Next page
    Next keyword
    IE.Quit
    
End Sub
```

I can only get all the titles, but i want to get the corresponding URLs for each title as well.
Does anyone know what is the problem?